# VS code,cant find the downloaded files from web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

ive been using requests and beautiful soup to web scrape and created a code where if i type in a term (for ex,i type in the word mike tyson the code will scrape the internet and find pictures of him)

but i cant find the downloaded images,so i thought its because it didnt specify the directory and created another stack of code which specified the directory,yet i still cant find the downloaded images

Comment: search your hard drive for a known file name, log the names of the pictures you download and search for one of them. Do you save the images?

Comment: Are you sure your code is doing what you try to describe? Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a path in the code, the file is generally saved in the user folder, for example: `C:\Users\Admin`.